# Solar Cycle 25: Can a strong solar storm trigger a violent geomagnetic shift?

Tags: climate, sun

**In light** of the material presented in the link, hopefully not disregarded as a complete mumbo-jumbo, I would like to pose a simple question, as mentioned above in the question -

**While we are entering Solar Cycle 25: Can a strong solar storm trigger a violent geomagnetic shift**?

[Research](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBIlzWTTOnU&t=27s). Thank you for reasoned, precise and specific replies.

Comment: what is a violent geomagnetic shift? the link you provide is useless and does not explain anything.

Comment: According to the Pittsburgh supercomputer simulation of a geomagnetic shift this is a violent change of polarities that leads to multiple 'Norths' and 'Souths' lasting anything from centuries to thousands of years until it stabilizes, unlike what is professed nowadays that it is a 'harmless' transition,the source is here: https://www.psc.edu/science/glatzmaier.html What follows is that the general geomagnetic field is at all times low and any form of cosmic events and Sun-Earth behavior (Magnetic Storms, High-Density Plasma; High-Speed Solar winds hitting Earth) is having a much greater impact

Comment: Given the past records of ferric rock layers it is significant enough to change the magnetization direction, that is the main source of our knowledge regarding the previous pole reversals.

Comment: No! Solar storms can produce more intense auroras & damage surface electrical infrastructure, but they do not influence the strength or direction of the Earth's magnetic field.

Comment: Please edit the answers you give in comments into your questionn as well - comments can disappear.

Answer (score 4):

> Can a strong solar storm trigger a violent geomagnetic shift?

## No.

---

Geomagnetic shifts (whether violent or not, whatever that means) are caused by changes in the Earth's core.

Solar activity only affects the atmosphere and Earth's surface. The shape of Earth's magnetic field can affect how the solar activity interacts with Earth. For example, the intensity and location of auroras, or whether satellite and communication operations will be disrupted or not. The solar activity can slightly change the magnetic field lines, but it will only happen for the duration of the storm itself.

Solar activity cannot cause any permanent shift or reversal in Earth's magnetic field.

Comment: Correct, afaik, but it would benefit from linking out to some source material that explains our understanding of the geomagnetic dynamo, such as this exhaustive review paper at https://journals.aps.org/rmp/pdf/10.1103/RevModPhys.72.1081: "It will be apparent to all readers who have had the stamina to read this review through that geodynamo theory already explains, at least qualitatively, virtually every known facet of the geomagnetic field described in Sec. I.C." If solar storms were capable of significantly affecting Earth's magnetic field, we'd see it in the paleomagnetic record.